# Can I use decorator under the terms?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have my own python library. And I use the decorator `@send_transport` from it.

```
@send_transport(program_version=__version__, entity=1)
def post(self):
    pass
```

Can I implement something like this?

```
try:
    from spo_client import send_transport    
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    @send_transport(program_version=__version__, entity=1)
def post(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Shall the `def post` and `pass` be indented?

Comment: You could try it, and see that it won't work. You should simply define `send_transport` as a noop function upon `ImportError`.

Comment: No, that's not valid syntax, but you could just create a no-op decorator: `except ImportError: send_transport = lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: func`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, you can do

```
try:
    from spo_client import send_transport    
    decorator = send_transport(program_version=__version__, entity=1)
except ImportError:
    decorator = lambda f: f

@decorator
def post(self):
    pass
```

This creates either the "correct" decorator or a dummy on which will transform the function into itself, i. e. leave it alone.

Another option could be to define a dummy `send_transport` function:

```
def dummy_send_transport(*a, **k):
    return lambda f: f

try:
    from spo_client import send_transport    
except ImportError:
    send_transport = dummy_send_transport
    # or just send_transport = lambda *a, **k: lambda f: f
    # but then the code would be less self-documenting.

@send_transport(program_version=__version__, entity=1)
def post(self):
    pass
```

In this case, on an import error, the `send_transport()` is substituted by a version which just returns a NOP decorator, but which can be called as its "original". Here, you can have several different `send_transport` calls in your code and don't have to predefine a variable for them.